# Show only rows that changed over time

Tags: php, mysql

We have some properties whose owners and area may change over time. I want to show states (default and last state) of properties which state changed during time (default v last state differs = default v last row in table differs).

Having table `states`:

```
stateID propertyID  owner          area timestamp    stateYear
1       1           David Smith    20   123456789    2017
2       2           Amanda Green   74   123456799    2017
3       1           David Smith    19   123456999    2017
1       3           Amanda Green   12   123459999    2018
2       1           David Smith    20   123499999    2018
3       4           Jack Stone     62   123999999    2018
4       2           Amanda Green   73   129999999    2018
```

What is default state of each property is inserted in table `properties`:

```
propertyID  userID  defaultStateID  defaultStateYear
1           1       1               2017
2           1       2               2017
3           2       1               2018
4           3       3               2018
```

Here is the code I tried to use:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM properties p JOIN
     (SELECT s2.propertyID, s2.owner as owner, s2.area as area, max(s2.timestamp) as maxtimestamp
      FROM states s2
      GROUP BY s2.propertyID
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT owner) >= 2 OR/** where owner changed **/
      COUNT(DISTINCT area) >= 2/** or where area changed **/
     ) sp
     ON sp.propertyID = p.propertyID JOIN
     states s
     ON s.propertyID = p.propertyID AND
        (/** default state + last state **/
         (s.stateYear = p.defaultStateYear AND
         s.stateId = p.defaultStateID) OR
         s.timestamp = sp.maxtimestamp
        )
WHERE p.userID = 1/** only properties of user 1 **/
ORDER BY sp.propertyID ASC, s.stateYear ASC, s.stateID ASC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b3a1/2) with my code.

What I expect to get is couple of states (default + last state) for each property whose states changed during time (default against last state) for specified user.

However, my code shows states even for properties where changes occurred in the meantime between default and last state (but default and last state are the same) - which I don't want to get.

Expected result:

```
stateID propertyID  owner           area    timestamp   stateYear
2       2           Amanda Green    74      123456799   2017
4       2           Amanda Green    73      129999999   2018
```

Comment: You should also post the expected result for the given sample data.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, I added expected result.

Comment: And what is the primary key in the `states` table? Or at leas a logical unique key?

Comment: Primary key in `states` is a combination of stateID + stateYear (I know, not fortunate, it is due to historical development).

Comment: Here is my first attempt: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b3a1/11 - But I also get states 1 (default) and 2 (last) for `propertyID = 1`

Comment: Although you tried completely different code, we both got basically the same result. And we both know result for propertyID 1 shouldn't be there. It seems your code doesn't compare owner and area between default and last state

Comment: I must disagree. IMHO the results are correct. For propertyID 1 defaultStateID  is 1. But the last state is 2.

Comment: If the area may not be the same: Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b3a1/17

Comment: Results are incorrect as stated in original post. Default and last state of propertyID 1 are identical which rules propertyID 1 out of correct results.

Comment: Your last fiddle shows correct result. Can you just add check for owner change (it may change like area)? Can you please also comment on your use of IN and <> operators?

Comment: Sorry need to go.. Might check it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171394/discussion-between-john-peeterson-and-paul-spiegel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is correct, even though it returns the expected result (due to non complete sample data).

However - The following query will return the *default state* and *last state* but in in a single row per `propertyID`:

```
SELECT p.propertyID
     , ds.stateID   as defaultStateId
     , ds.stateYear as defaultStateYear
     , ls.stateID   as lastStateId
     , ls.stateYear as lastStateYear
FROM properties p
JOIN states ds -- default state
  ON  ds.propertyID = p.propertyID
  AND ds.stateID    = p.defaultStateID
JOIN states ls -- last state
  ON  ls.propertyID = p.propertyID
  AND ls.timestamp  = (
    SELECT MAX(s.timestamp)
    FROM states s
    WHERE s.propertyID = p.propertyID
  )
WHERE p.userID = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b3a1/21

Result:

```
| propertyID | defaultStateId | defaultOwner | defaultArea | defaultTimestamp | defaultStateYear | lastStateId |    lastOwner | lastArea | lastTimestamp | lastStateYear |
|------------|----------------|--------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|-------------|--------------|----------|---------------|---------------|
|          1 |              1 |  David Smith |          20 |        123456789 |             2017 |           2 |  David Smith |       20 |     123499999 |          2018 |
|          2 |              2 | Amanda Green |          74 |        123456799 |             2017 |           4 | Amanda Green |       73 |     129999999 |          2018 |
```

Finding the row with default state is kind of trivial `ds.stateID    = p.defaultStateID` - but there should only be one corresponding entry.

For the "last" row we can use a `SELECT MAX(s.timestamp)` subquery in the ON clause.

Now - having this - we can add additional filters in the WHERE clause.

Last state must be different from default state:

```
AND ls.stateID <> p.defaultStateID
```

Area and owner must be different in the two selected rows:

```
AND ls.area    <> ds.area
AND ls.owner   <> ds.owner
```

But note that this is not the same as "has changed over time". Because they might be equal in the two rows, but have another value in a row between them. And that will return no rows for your sample data. So I now need to guess your requerements. If you mean "Area **or** owner must be different" - then it would be

```
AND (ls.area <> ds.area OR ls.owner <> ds.owner)
```

Now it returns the expected result. But you might also just be lucky.

If you need the data in two separate rows, you can add another join to the query

```
JOIN states s
  ON (s.stateID, s.stateYear) IN (
     (ds.stateID, ds.stateYear),
     (ls.stateID, ls.stateYear)
  )
```

You should use the primary key here to identify the *default* and the *last* state. Another way for the join condition would be

```
JOIN states s
  ON (s.stateID = ds.stateID AND s.stateYear = ds.stateYear)
  OR (s.stateID = ls.stateID AND s.stateYear = ls.stateYear)
```

I'm not sure if MySQL is able to optimize one of of those conditions.

The final query might be something like

```
SELECT s.*
FROM properties p
JOIN states ds -- default state
  ON  ds.propertyID = p.propertyID
  AND ds.stateID    = p.defaultStateID
JOIN states ls -- last state
  ON  ls.propertyID = p.propertyID
  AND ls.timestamp  = (
    SELECT MAX(s.timestamp)
    FROM states s
    WHERE s.propertyID = p.propertyID
  )
JOIN states s
  ON (s.stateID = ds.stateID AND s.stateYear = ds.stateYear)
  OR (s.stateID = ls.stateID AND s.stateYear = ls.stateYear)
WHERE p.userID = 1
  AND ls.stateID <> p.defaultStateID
  AND (ls.area <> ds.area OR ls.owner <> ds.owner)
ORDER BY s.propertyID ASC, s.stateYear ASC, s.stateID ASC;
```

returning the expected result

```
| stateID | propertyID |        owner | area | timestamp | stateYear |
|---------|------------|--------------|------|-----------|-----------|
|       2 |          2 | Amanda Green |   74 | 123456799 |      2017 |
|       4 |          2 | Amanda Green |   73 | 129999999 |      2018 |
```